# Trigger a ADF Pipeline via REST API and pass a parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to run an adf pipeline through a rest api and pass a parameter or variable to the pipeline?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @willy, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can.

Example: Creates a run of a pipeline with optional parameters:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01&referencePipelineRunId={referencePipelineRunId}&isRecovery={isRecovery}&startActivityName={startActivityName}&startFromFailure={startFromFailure}
```

For more details, please ref this document [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/Pipelines/CreateRun):
[image]

HTH.

Comment: like this? 
endpoint = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01'

response = requests.post(endpoint, 
                        headers=auth_header, 
                        json={"properties":{"parameters":{"parameter1": "This is parameter1", "parameter2": "This is parameter2"}}}
                        )